# Find the element with the most text

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, string-length

It's like this:

```
text = $('#content').find('.text'),
length = 0;
longest = '';

$(text).each(function(){

  if($(this).text().length > length){
    length = $(this).text().length;
    longest = $(this);        
  }       

});

alert($(longest).text());
```

But can I do it without the loop? I mean somehow directly select the longest text element? Because this is too slow

Comment: you cannot do it without the loop.. because you have to check all the elements..

Comment: Caching the objects will help you.

Comment: nothing can be done, maybe cache `$(this)` and also `varthis.text().length`, also not sure if faster but definitely better would be to avoid globals and the updating of them, like just add a `return varmaxlen` to your function

Comment: Why is it too slow? Too many elements, or it has to be done too often?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it without a loop.  There is no built-in DOM function to find the element with the longest text, thus some piece of code has to iterate through them and find which one is longest.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code:

```
var longestSoFar = -1;
var longestItem;

$('#content .text').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text.length > longestSoFar) {
        longestSoFar = text.length;
        longestItem = this;
    }       
});

alert($(longestItem).text());
```

---

The only other thing I can think of would be to first compare heights of `.text` elements and find the ones that taller than the others and then compare text length in just those.  This is probably a lot quicker than computing the actual length of the text, but whether it would be useful or not depends upon your layout and whether height would be an accurate filter or not.

---

To speed it up further, we'd probably have to see what your HTML generally looks like to have an idea of where the slow-down is coming from.  `.text()` isn't a particularly fast operation because it has to walk all the text nodes in a given element and accumulate all their text.  If there's only one node in the element, it's quick, but if there's lots of involved HTML in the node, then it has a lot of nodes and childnodes to walk to find all the text nodes.

---

Note, in your code you were making a jQuery object out of something that was already a jQuery object.  It works that way, but it's a waste of a function call when it's already a jQuery object.

Comment: I am too paranoid on the default len, I would make the default longest `-1` or use `>=`, because I don't know what happens if everyone is 0 len, and we make a call to `longestItem.text()` but with an empty `longestItem`

Comment: @ajax333221 - OK, I'll change it to `-1` so it could find an item with no text if that's all there was.  I'm not sure what behavior the OP actually wants.  Perhaps they don't want to find an empty object.  FYI, `$(undefined).text()` returns an empty string as jQuery protects pretty seriously against anything you pass there so there would have been no problem with the way it was.  It really depends upon what behavior the OP wants when there is no text.

Comment: now I am paranoid our `-1` comments will involuntary make people -1 your answer subconsciously, you see... I am really a paranoic guy

Answer (score 1):

The plain script version is pretty similar:

```
var longestSoFar = -1;
var longestItem;
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#content .text');

for (var i=0, iLen=els.length, len; i<iLen; i++) {
  len = (els[i].textContent || els[i].innerText).length;
  if ( len > longestSoFar) {
    longestItem = els[i];
    longestSoFar = len;
  }
}

alert(longestItem.textContent || longestItem.innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vpFwL/)

[**fiddle DEMO-1**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MetJt/3/)

```
var con = $('#content');
var arr = con.find('.text').map(function () {
    return $(this).text().length;
}).get();
var longest = arr.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math,arr));
alert($('#content .text:nth-child(' + ++longest + ')').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way use `get()` to save it to `Array` and then sort the array with a custom sort using a function which uses length as way of sorting and not in alphabetical order, like:

```
var listitems = $(".text").get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
      var compA = $(a).text().length;
      var compB = $(b).text().length;
return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;});

// Get the last element of the array which has the longest length
alert("Longest = "+$(listitems[listitems.length-1]).text());
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MetJt/2/)